# Unable to setup Kerberos on Ubuntu 14.04 - krb5kdc: No such file or directory - while initializing database for realm myrealm

Tags: ubuntu, installation, kerberos

I'm attempting to follow the guide on the Ubuntu wiki for installing and setting up Kerberos. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) 64-bit. I have setup avahi-daemon in order to provide .local DNS names. I have then run:

```
sudo apt-get install krb5-kdc krb5-admin-server
```

The dialog asks me for a realm, as well as the hostname of the server, both of which I enter. However, it then seems to hit an error:

```
krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm myrealm - see log file for details
...fail!
```

The only problem - there is no logfile. It seems the default `/etc/krb5.conf` doesn't actually have logging enabled. Anyhow, I add the following to it:

```
[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5.log
```

and then try running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure krb5-kdc
```

It still errors out, but this time, in `/var/log/krb5.log`, I see:

```
krb5kdc: No such file or directory - while initializing database for realm myrealm
```

However, it doesn't actually tell me what file or directory is missing.

This is my `krb5.conf`

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = myrealm

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
        krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
        krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true

# The following encryption type specification will be used by MIT Kerberos
# if uncommented.  In general, the defaults in the MIT Kerberos code are
# correct and overriding these specifications only serves to disable new
# encryption types as they are added, creating interoperability problems.
#
# Thie only time when you might need to uncomment these lines and change
# the enctypes is if you have local software that will break on ticket
# caches containing ticket encryption types it doesn't know about (such as
# old versions of Sun Java).

#       default_tgs_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#       default_tkt_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#       permitted_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1

# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
        v4_instance_resolve = false
        v4_name_convert = {
                host = {
                        rcmd = host
                        ftp = ftp
                }
                plain = {
                        something = something-else
                }
        }
        fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5.log
[realms]
        myrealm = {
                kdc = kerberos-myname-syd.local
                admin_server = kerberos-myname-syd.local
        }
        ATHENA.MIT.EDU = {
                kdc = kerberos.mit.edu:88
                kdc = kerberos-1.mit.edu:88
                kdc = kerberos-2.mit.edu:88
                admin_server = kerberos.mit.edu
                default_domain = mit.edu
<cut>

[domain_realm]
        .mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        mit.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        .media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
        media.mit.edu = MEDIA-LAB.MIT.EDU
        .csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
        csail.mit.edu = CSAIL.MIT.EDU
        .whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        whoi.edu = ATHENA.MIT.EDU
        .stanford.edu = stanford.edu
        .slac.stanford.edu = SLAC.STANFORD.EDU
        .toronto.edu = UTORONTO.CA
        .utoronto.ca = UTORONTO.CA

[login]
        krb4_convert = true
        krb4_get_tickets = false
~
~
```

This is my `/etc/krb5/kdc.conf` file:

```
[kdcdefaults]
    kdc_ports = 750,88

[realms]
    myrealm = {
        database_name = /var/lib/krb5kdc/principal
        admin_keytab = FILE:/etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
        acl_file = /etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
        key_stash_file = /etc/krb5kdc/stash
        kdc_ports = 750,88
        max_life = 10h 0m 0s
        max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
        master_key_type = des3-hmac-sha1
        supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal arcfour-hmac:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-crc:normal des:normal des:v4 des:norealm des:onlyrealm des:afs3
        default_principal_flags = +preauth
    }
```

Any thoughts on what's going on?

Answer (score 16):

You need to create a database first:

```
kdb5_util create -s -r MYREALM
```

Where `MYREALM` matches the realm name in your `/var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf` file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `myrealm` should be upper case, matching `krb5.conf`, e.g. `ATHENA.MIT.EDU`

Answer (score 2):

I would do a full apt-get remove --purge and try following this tutorial.  http://techpubs.spinlocksolutions.com/dklar/kerberos.html

Comment: run the command with sudo, else it will say Permission denied